# LRU caching of images in gridview is not working

Tags: android

Ive read and watched every possible tutorial about caching of image but couldnt find a solution for this.
i am using an async tesk to load images to gridview cells.

1-inside gridview of the adapter i am checking if that bitmap is already found in cache before calling the loading task.

2-in asynctask im saving the loaded bitmap to the cache.
BUT the cache is always empty so bitmaps are not saved. 
im posting my adapter and asynctask.
Note: i used the exact tutorial of android developers

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#config-changes
thanks in advance

```
    public class FragmentCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       public FragmentCellAdapter(Context context,String json,int test){
    mcontext=context;    
    this.Json = json;  //something i use in my code

    s = test;

    try {
        this.jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024 );
// Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
    Log.e("maxMemory and cach is ",""+maxMemory +" "+ cacheSize);

  memoryCache =   new LruCache<String,Bitmap>(cacheSize){
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
            Log.e("size of returns "," " + bitmap.getByteCount()/1024);
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        }
    };

}


      @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    Log.e("calling get item of grid adpter","at position " + position);
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return jsonArray.length();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view;


         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragmentcell,null);
         cellIm = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cellimage2);
          final  Bitmap bitmap1 = getBitmapFromMemCache(imgurl);
            if (bitmap1 == null){
                new LoadImage(cellIm,b).execute("http://restaurantapp.azurewebsites.net/images/menuItems/"+image);
                Log.e("null bitmap calling task  at position ", + position+      " is : " +"http://restaurantapp.azurewebsites.net/images/menuItems/"+image);

               }
            else {

                cellIm.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);Log.e("bitmap found in ","                               cache") ;}
      return view;
   }

       public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
  if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
    Log.e("adding image url",key);
    memoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
  }
     public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    if (memoryCache.get(key) == null){Log.e("null at key",key);}
    return memoryCache.get(key);
   }


      public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    WeakReference<ProgressBar> pbar;

    public LoadImage (ImageView im) {
        this.imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(im);
       // this.pbar = new WeakReference<ProgressBar>(bar);
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)           url.openConnection();

            int responsecode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("code of res"," " + responsecode);
            if (responsecode == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(50,50);
           resizedBitmap  = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,100,150);

            // adding bitmaps to the cache
            addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(url),resizedBitmap);}
            else {Log.e("response code ",responsecode + "");}


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmapp) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmapp);

        ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        ProgressBar bar = pbar.get();

        if (imageView != null){
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapp);}

    }
```

the problem is everytime getview() calls the task because bitmaps in cache are null.
Thanks again

Comment: If you want to show images in grid view  as mentioned then you can use below libraries for effective solution: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Google's Volley already has everything you need to achieve this without the need to use async tasks. Take a look at this link https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/volley/request.html#request-image

Comment: @himanshumunjal   i dont want to use libraries i believe there is a small trick i a missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew the problem after adding logs:

1st: the tutorial provided by android developers creates a cash of around 8000 bytes which is too small to store bitmaps.

so i changed the size to 4mb or 4*1024*1024 which can store a decent number of bitmaps according to their own size.you can set any size but you have to check that the size of LRUCache is much bigger than the value you get from  sizeOf method which gives the size of every entry .In this way you can calculate the approximate numbers of bitmaps your cache can store.

Comment: also avoid using libraries they only make your app heavier especially for such small things

Answer (score 2):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Creating caching library is not a trivial task at all. Use already developed library([Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)) or at least read the sources.

Comment: again i do not want to use any library everything is working just fine but something is missing in the caching thing